# Error loading Audio file from Library using Linkage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, loops

I a having trouble loading an audio file from the library, I was previously loading the sound files externally  like so:

var s1:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Sound/Melody1.mp3"));

However I now need to load them from the library as I have encountered a looping problem with mp3 files.

Below is my attempt, however I am receiving the error:
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 21  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method attachSound through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound.

/* Click to Play/Stop Sound 1
Clicking on the symbol instance plays the specified sound.
Clicking on the symbol instance a second time stops the sound.
*/

Btn_Melody1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound1);

var fl_SC1:SoundChannel;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to play or stop the sound
var fl_ToPlay1:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound1(evt:MouseEvent):void

{

```
if (fl_ToPlay1)

{
    var s1:Sound = new Sound();
    s1.attachSound("Melody1");
    fl_SC1 = s1.play(0,999);

}
else
{
    fl_SC1.stop();
}
fl_ToPlay1 = ! fl_ToPlay1;
```

}

I can't see what I am doing wrong, any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing AS3, there is no `attachSound` method on `MovieClip` (see [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)) (exist in AS2).

In order to use a sound in the library.

1 - add a linkage name to the sound (ex : `Sound0`);

2 - instanciate your sound :

```
var sound : Sound = new Sound0();
//do nasty stuff with your sound !
```

Comment: Thanks man, worked perfectly :)
I am still learning and sometimes get confused between AS2 & AS3.

Comment: @user1414344 - you need to click on the tick to mark this answer, and it will improve your reputation and you will get more help next time, welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Oh I see, I was trying to up vote and it wouldn't let me.
My bad.

Thanks Neil and sorry OXMO456